# Excel - Column with numbers laid out like MMYYYY (Ex. 022014), Would like to convert these to a real date

Tags: excel, date

Excel - Column with numbers laid out like MMYYYY (Ex. 022014), Would like to convert these to a real date (with no day).  Text to columns does not have the option for just month year.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: are the leading zeroes part of a string value or number formatting?

Comment: That is because a real date requires a day, whether it is displayed or not is a function of number format.

Comment: btw, any 'real date' will have a day whether you use it or not. probably best to default it to 1 (first day of the month).

Comment: Try this `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,2)&"/1/"&RIGHT(A1,4))`

Comment: If you use the MDY option in Text to Columns it will work, but you'll get `2/20/14` as your date.  With a custom format of mm/yyyy it will look like you've requested.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your date is in `B2`, in another cell use the following formula.  Copy down as required:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(B2,4),LEFT(B2,2),1)
```

Custom format your cell as required such as MMYYYY.

Excel will require a day as part of its system.  I choose 1 as the day since every month has a 1st of the month, but not every month has a 31st, 30th, or 29th.